# set proxy settings programmatically on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, configuration, proxy

Im trying to configure proxy programmatically on OS X 10.10.
scutil --proxy
 shows correct settings and the system actually uses them, but new settings don't appear on the proxy tab on Network preferences(in System Preferences).

```
 SCDynamicStoreRef dynamicStore = SCDynamicStoreCreate(NULL, CFSTR(APP_NAME), NULL, NULL);
 CFDictionaryRef ipv4key = SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(dynamicStore, CFSTR("State:/Network/Global/IPv4"));
 CFStringRef primaryServiceId = CFDictionaryGetValue(ipv4key,  CFSTR("PrimaryService"));
 CFStringRef primaryServicePath = CFStringCreateWithFormat(NULL, NULL, CFSTR("Setup:/Network/Service/%@/Proxies"), primaryServiceId);
 CFDictionaryRef proxySettings = SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(dynamicStore, primaryServicePath);
 //clone currnt values for update new values
 CFMutableDictionaryRef mutableProxySettings = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 0, proxySettings);
```

then for each value I do 
    CFStringRef host= ...;

```
 CFDictionaryReplaceValue(mutableProxySettings, kSCPropNetProxiesHTTPProxy, host);
```

Then

```
 Boolean success = SCDynamicStoreSetValue(dynamicStore, primaryServicePath, mutableProxySettings);
```

Settings get updated, but don't appear on proxy tab How to make them appear there?